# How is the Selenitic Age solvable in Myst?

Tags: myst

Warning: Contains spoilers!

In the Selenitic Age, while you are going through the maze to get back to Myst Island, and you use the "directional sounds" to figure out which way to go through the maze.

However, these sounds are taught to the player in the Mechanical Age. It's entirely reasonable that one would visit the Selenitic Age, and therefore wouldn't have been able to learn the sounds which indicate direction beforehand.

Therefore, it would be unreasonable if there was not also some indication in the Selenitic Age of which noise points in which direction. However, I cannot seem to find it.

Where is it? :)

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Didn't know such a tag existed.

Comment: selenitic-age?  It probably shouldn't as it's way too specific.

Comment: To hide spoilers, you can use the spoiler tag (`>!` in front of the lines) see [my meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/help-for-the-spoiler-givers)

Comment: I read a (many spoilers careful) guide [here](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/idx/l/lvg/9835611.0001.001/--myst-and-riven-the-world-of-the-dni?g=dculture;trgt=pb_67;view=fulltext;xc=1) and that suggests the sound correlation was an accident!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i remember correctly, the first intersection you come to the game will play a sound.  At this point, there is only one way to go -- so that direction is that sound.  Continue on, and it should be pretty straight-forward (maybe one or two backtracks).

I didn't even know there was a key to the sounds anywhere.  Just deduction.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible. If you go the wrong way eventually it will loop forever. Even without that, you would have hundreds of millions of possible paths. There's no way to deduce that.

Comment: First intersection (after you start), you can only go west (and the sound for west is played).  Second you can only go North (sound for north is played). Third you can go two directions (but one is immediately a dead end).  Only one sound left, and that has to be south.  map link(def a spoiler!):[link](http://db.gamefaqs.com/computer/doswin/file/myst_selentic.png)

Comment: +1: This is exactly how I solved this puzzle the first time I played the game.

Comment: @BillyONeal Heck, I did it the classic "pen and paper" dungeoneering way, and got through. (And then hit Mechanical, heard the sounds, made the connection and was righteously irked at taking a couple hours to do something that had a cheat sheet so handy!)

Comment: @circusdei Your link is busted (gamefaqs puts up a "we don't let external sites link to our files" page).

Comment: copy the link, and paste it into the address bar.

Comment: Not only does the wrong exit from the third area immediately dead-end, but it's also the same direction as one that you already know the sound for.  This is assuming you know that the sound is the key,

Answer (score 1):

If you track your way through the Selenitic Age, you will begin to see patterns in the paths you take and that the tracks will eventually "loop" around (probably just defaulting back to the start). You can determine the full, correct path via this method although I do not recommend doing this at all.

Comment: You can see someone doing just this (deliberately) as part of their Let's Play: WARNING Spoilers: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHzdNKv06uM&feature=channel_video_title

Comment: It is actually something I graphed out on paper too until I got so frustrated I bought a guide book to get past it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no loops in the Selenitic Age maze.  Consequently, you can map it out using either the [right-hand rule or the left-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm#Wall_follower) for maze-solving to reach the exit (the right-hand rule, ie. taking the rightward-most tunnel every time you reach a junction, is faster than the left-hand rule).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late reply, but:

In the book about Selenitic Age in the Myst library, Atrus suggests that the mysteries of the selenitic age might find an answer in other ages. This is a suggestion for the player to do this age as the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is a reference to the sounds in the Selenitic Age. I've seen no notation regarding the directions and you really can't map it out in relation to the island.

Every walkthrough I could find doesn't have reference to another clue.

There might be some clue somewhere, but I'm unaware of it.

EDIT: I found a post on a forum, and this is all they had to offer...

"OK, have you noticed that the mazerunner makes a noise every time you stop? You can work out the directions from the first few stops, or go back to Mechanical to refresh your memory."